# How to load and display data with React from an API running on localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I'm getting an error "app.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" with my code below.**

I'm trying to use React to display data from my Drupal API, that's running on my localhost.
In the React app, I'm using a simple HTTP server (python -m SimpleHTTPServer) to prevent XMLHttpRequest errors, and I have enabled CORS on my API. And instead of jQuery, I'm using Axios.

I can't get index.html to display anything else than the text "Event!", what am I doing wrong? Here is my app.js

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var th = this;
    this.serverRequest = 
      axios.get(this.props.source)
        .then(function(event) {    
          th.setState({
            title: event.title[0].value
          });
        })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Event!</h1>
        <h2>{this.state.title}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App source="http://localhost:8888/drupal/api/events" />,
     document.getElementById('container')
);
```

And here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container"></div>

<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/jquery@3.1.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I can't get anything else than the text "Event!" to show up, what am I doing wrong? 
Here is a screenshot of part of my API, that shows an example of the title I'm trying to display "EspooCine".

[image]

If I add console.log on ComponentDidMount(), e.g.:

```
componentDidMount() {
    var th = this;
    this.serverRequest =     axios.get(this.props.source).then(function(result) {    
           console.log(result);
    })
}
```

Then I get the following on the console:

[image]

Comment: Pro tip: since you're already using ES6 classes, start writing your functions using ES6 arrow syntax: `(event) => this.setState({ title: event.title[0].value})` Arrow functions lexically bind `this`, meaning you won't need to do `var th = this` anymore. On the same note, start using `let` and `const` instead of `var`.

Comment: Can you check your console and see if the page is actually loading the local file? Your React/JSX seems fine with a quick read, so I'm guessing it's an issue with your AJAX request.

Comment: Thanks, I now checked with my console, and it's loading the local file. On the browser, I can see the text "Event!" inside the <h2> tags, but nothing else.

Comment: I'm getting an error "app.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

Comment: That means that the `title` field within your `event` response doesn't exist. Verify the data that is being returned by the endpoint.

Comment: Console log the event and check if title is one of the keys sent back with the event. There could be another layer of data that was sent back, and then you would need a different key chain to access the title you're looking for. What does console logging event give you?

Comment: I console.log()'d the event and added the results above in the end of the problem description. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axios promises yield a response object on success that has a `data` property containing the body of the response; it appears that you are trying to access the [0] property of the response object, not of its `data`, which will be the Array you expect. Also, it looks like there are other mistakes made accessing the structure. Try this or something similar:

```
axios.get(this.props.source).then(event => {    
  th.setState({
    title: event.data[0].title[0].value
  });
});
```